# Web deploy. Close connection after 2-3 files, Unable to write data to the transport connection

Tags: iis, webdeploy

While using Web Deploy with Visual Studio 2010, it automatically loads the first 2 or 3 files and then the connexion is cut:

Output :

```
Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Defau ...
Ajout de l'enfant dirPath (Add\bin).
Ajout de l'enfant dirPath (Add\ClientBin).
Ajout de l'enfant dirPath (Add\ClientBin\ProfilePicture).
Mise à jour de setAcl (Add).
Mise à jour de setAcl (Add).
Ajout de l'enfant filePath (Add\Analyze.XML).
Ajout de l'enfant filePath (Add\bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll).
```

Error : Web deployment task failed. (Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Could this be a file size or a time-out problem? I have checked with the host and the firewall doesn't have any restrictions. Could this be an IIS configuration issue?

Any ideas?

Benjamin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem:

I created new Web Site with new Application Pool (i didn't use DefaultAppPool). After i used .Net V4.0 in my new application pool.

(Do not forget add user in "Configure Web Deploy Publishing...")

And it's working.

good day.